# How to shrink data set output from avi file

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a data set from an avi file I have and I know I've made a mistake somewhere.

The Avi file I have is 1,827 KB (4:17) but after running my code to convert the frames into arrays of number I now have a file that is 1,850,401 KB. This seems a little large to me.

How can I reduce the size of my data set / where did I go wrong?

```
# Program To Read video 
# and Extract Frames 
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import time

# Function to extract frames 
def FrameCapture(path): 

    # Path to video file 
    vidObj = cv2.VideoCapture(path) 

    # Used as counter variable 
    count = 0

    # checks whether frames were extracted 
    success = 1

    newDataSet = []
    try:
        while success: 

            # vidObj object calls read 
            # function extract frames 
            success, image = vidObj.read()

            img_reverted = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
            new_img = img_reverted / 255.0

            newDataSet.append(new_img)
            #new_img >> "frame%d.txt" % count
            # Saves the frames with frame-count 
            #cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image) 

            count += 1
    except:
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        np.save("DataSet" + timestr , newDataSet)

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Calling the function 
    FrameCapture("20191212-150041output.avi")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the video mainly consist of similar pixels blocked together that the video have compressed to such a low file size. When you load single images into arrays all that compression goes away and depending on the fps of the video you will have thousands of uncompressed images. When you first load an image it will be saved as a numpy array of dtype uint8 and the image size will be WIDTH * HEIGHT * N_COLOR_CHANNELS bytes. After you divide it with 255.0 to normalize between 0 and 1 the dtype changes to float64 and the image size increases eightfold. You can use this information to calculate expected size of the images.

So your options is to either decrease the height and width of your images (downscale), change to grayscale or if your application allows it to stick with uint8 values. If the images doesn't change too much and you don't need thousands of them you could also only save every 10th or whatever seems reasonable. If you need them all as is but they don't fit in memory consider using a generator to load them on demand. It will be slower but at least it will run.